# Recycler View inside Custom View doesn't showing

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-custom-view

I do have a problem with a RecyclerView inside a Custom View using Constraint Layout as a root container, sometimes the recycler is showing properly but other times it doesn't show. If someone else has experienced the same issue, please let me know how can I fix it.

This is the xml of my view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <View
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/generic_dimen_0dp"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/generic_dimen_1dp"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    android:background="@color/tabs_border_gray"/>

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                    android:id="@+id/recentlyViewedTitle"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/custom_margin_20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/generic_dimen_35dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/es_web_med"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:padding="@dimen/custom_margin_5dp"
                    android:text="Frequently Bought Together"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/productsRecycler"/>


                <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/productsRecycler"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:clipToPadding="false"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:paddingHorizontal="@dimen/custom_margin_20dp"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
                    tools:itemCount="4"
                    tools:listitem="@layout/item_frequently_bought_together" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</layout>
```

And this is the kt file for the Custom View

```
class FrequentlyBoughtTogetherComponent @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyleAttr: Int = ZERO,
) : ConstraintLayout(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

    private val binding = FrequentlyBoughtTogetherComponentBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context), this, false)
    private var productsAdapter: FrequentlyBoughtTogetherAdapter? = null

    init {
        setView()
        addView(binding.root)
    }

    private fun setView() = binding.run {
        productsAdapter = FrequentlyBoughtTogetherAdapter()
        productsRecycler.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false)
        productsRecycler.adapter = productsAdapter
    }

    fun updateProducts(products: List<RecommendationProduct>) {
        productsAdapter?.submitList(products)
    }
}
```

I'm updating the recycler data through the updateProducts function.

I've tried to setted the layoutManager inside the custom view, thinking that maybe that is the problem

Comment: You're not using your custom view in the XML file shown above.

Comment: Try removing the <layout> as the root. Replace it directly with your <ConstraintLayout>. Let me know if this solves your problem

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare your view by it's name and total path to it.

Example, I've created `MyView` class. Here I declare it in my xml:

[image]